# How to read and compare data from an SQL Server Express database

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sql-server-express

I am trying to create a select statement in C# to check if the value inserted into a textbox (userName) is in an existing SQL database. I have a database called `Employee` containing a table called `EVUSERS` and it has a column called `UName`.

In my code I have a method which takes the value from a textbox called UserBox. I would like to know if there is a temporary table where the select is stored which I can compare the textbox value to.

Here is the code:

```
private void CheckLoginExist()
{
            String userName = UserBox.Text;

            string connectionString = @"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Database=Employee;Integrated Security=true";
            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                using (SqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand())
                {

                    command.CommandText = "SELECT UName FROM EVUSERS WHERE UName = @UName";
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UName", userName);
                    connection.Open();
                    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    connection.Close();
                }
            }
}
```

I currently have a select but I am not sure how to display it and I am able to connect to the DB.

Comment: Your returning a single value (or null) so use `ExecuteScalar` as `ExecuteNonQuery` is for non-queries (which includes `select`)

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need [ExecuteScalar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), not ExecuteNonQuery

```
...
connection.Open();
var name = command.ExecuteScaclar().ToString();
connection.Close();

if (name != null) {
  MessageBox.Show("This name already exists");
  return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private void CheckLoginExist()
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    String userName = UserBox.Text;

   string connectionString = @"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Database=Employee;Integrated Security=true";
   using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
   {
         SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT UName FROM EVUSERS WHERE UName = '" + userName  + "'", _conn);                 
         da.Fill(dt); 
   }
}
```

Now you can do whatever you want to do with this DataTable.

Comment: Thanks. How would I perhaps, display in an if statement displaying a  messagebox if it returns true? What would be the argument that I would use? if(userName == this.userName)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Match");
            } thanks

Comment: How can I test this, to see if I have an existing username in the database. If I enter a value into the textbox which exists in the database, What can parameter I use that will check it. If I want a messagebox to pop up saying that username exists? Thank you again